# best position for explosive pushups

Tags: push-ups, explosiveness

When trying to do clap pushups or any pushup where both hands leave the ground is there an ideal hand positioning for maximizing power? I typically do them with my hands directly below my shoulders and wonder if I should use a wider stance for training/execution.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y53rXo2LT2s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I do push-ups, I do them to best match for the goal I'm trying to achieve. As an example when focusing on my triceps I choose a narrower hand position.

When focusing more on shoulders I prefer wider stances.

But in general I would suggest the most 'healthiest' one and that would be where you place your hands shoulder width appart and try not to flare your elbows out too much, rather they should be held more closer to your body. Your whole body should look like an arrow.

[image: symbolic picture]